# root is working for login ldap user, but not for regular user

Tags: ldap, openldap

I have a ldap server and a client. If as root I do on client : `su - ldapuser1` I get in as ldapuser1 with no need of typing password. But if I do `su - ldapuser1` as regular user, it will ask me for a password but it will say `su: incorrect password` Can someone tell me please what could be an issue. I can find nothing in logs.

If I do `ldapsearch -D "cn=manager,dc=contoso,dc=com" -W "cn=ldapuser1"` on server I get `result: 32 No such object`, but I do get `result: 0 Success` on client. Is this related?

Comment: I am using CentOs and did not yet configure TLS

Comment: I found out that if I add `ldap_tls_reqcert = never` to `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf` on client and restart the `sssd` service, I can log in successfully. But If I comment it the line that was added just before, restart the service, it still works. I would expect that it would not work again, so this is not rely a solution for me. Can someone explain me what is going on please?